# AWS CodeBuild errors out on PRE_BUILD step

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I am getting the following error when using an AWS managed image for Windows :-

> [Container] 2019/09/13 14:48:54 Command did not exit successfully aws s3 cp --recursive s3://unique-bucket-name/folder/ C:\temp\folder exit status 1
>
> [Container] 2019/09/13 14:48:58 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
>
> [Container] 2019/09/13 14:48:58 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: aws s3 cp --recursive s3://unique-bucket-name/folder/ C:\temp\folder. Reason: exit status 1

The `aws s3 cp` command runs fine for another command which pulls from a different S3 bucket (***size: 4.2 GB***, ***# of objects 1,526***). For this particular bucket (***size: 4.6 GB***, ***# of objects 2,06,462***), the `cp` command seems to be able to execute completely but the last step errors out with exit status 1.

There is no evident timeout issues as I have gone with default of 1 hour. The build run which errors out completes in ~25 minutes.

Can someone please help me fix this ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1) Check if bucket is configured with encryption key, try using command:
   $ aws s3 cp --sse aws:kms

... this uses default Server side encryption.

2) Add --debug to s3 cp command for some added debug output

Comment: (1)  The bucket has no encryption (2) `--debug` output didn't reveal anything new..

Comment: I have just gone ahead with a zip+download+unzip approach for now. The challenge was ref'ing the env var $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR and how it is interpreted for aws cli commands and native os commandline.